# Trouble connecting Node to MongoDB on Windows

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to run a node database.  It has been several months since I set it up (following a tutorial) and I can't figure out how to connect to it again.

Here is what I have tried.

```
cd C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin
```

This is the folder which node is installed.  Then I run the following:

```
mongod --dbpath d:\njs\nodetest1\data\
```

Which based on the following image, I would think should be correct, as the dbpath I list contains the following:

[image: Directory Image]

But then when I open a new instance of the command prompt, also navigate to  cd C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin and enter

```
mongo
show databases
```

The results are, two databases titled DB_DROPPED & LOCAL both wit 0GB.  I thought the database I'm looking for should be titled myCases, but that isn't showing up.

Does the picture I show suggest any cause?  Am I simply skipping a step to connect?  The database did not contain any sensitive information and I was just setting it up to test some stuff (and therefore had not been overly concerned with figuring out security), is it possible someone came in and "dropped" (i.e., deleted) the database?

Comment: Screenshots are generally the least efficient way to show information of this sort. They can't be indexed by search engines, they're often difficult to read, either too big or way too small, and clutter up your question with irrelevant details. Posting text, like you've done with your commands and config, is a significantly better way of doing this. Little things like this can help get answers faster, as well as help others benefit from your question.

Answer (score 0):

Using `mongod --dbpath d:\njs\nodetest1\data\`.You are setting data directory to store all data.now just start mongoDB using this command `"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\mongod.exe".`